# Crystal Report Permission Issue

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

We are using Crystal Report Export to PDF function.
Below is the code sample

```
Dim rptDoc As New ReportDocument
rptDoc.Load(AppConfig.SitePath + "Form201.rpt")

ExportOptions rptExportOption;
DiskFileDestinationOptions rptFileDestOption = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions rptFormatOption = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
string reportFileName = filePath;
rptFileDestOption.DiskFileName = reportFileName;
rptExportOption = rptDocument.ExportOptions;
rptExportOption.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
rptExportOption.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
rptExportOption.ExportDestinationOptions = rptFileDestOption;
rptExportOption.ExportFormatOptions = rptFormatOption;

rptDocument.Export(rptExportOption);
```

We have given write permission to everyone on temp folder. And given read and execute permission to everyone on C drive of server. Normally it works fine but in week or 10 days suddenly we start getting error .

Load report failed.

Invalid file name.

at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Testfile.GeneratePDF(Int32 cmpid)

This is the line causing the error

```
rptDoc.Load(AppConfig.SitePath + "Form201.rpt")
```

> When we reapply read and execute permission for everyone on C drive of the server
>   the issue is resolved.

Please suggest what permission we are missing as this issue reoccurs after every 7 to 10 days. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it intra-house app ? If so, check with sys/web admin as well about the security policies update .

Comment: Do you have a different drive you can write to? Even if it is a flash drive with a drive D? I think @Sami is on the right track with your permissions getting overwritten. What directory is the file being written to? Take a screenshot of the security permissions, then check again when the report can't write to the folder. Are the permissions different, especially parent security.

Comment: report file is located in one of the websites like C:\inetpub\vhosts\www.abc.com   . we have applied everyone permission on windows temp folder ..and thats not getting removed. to make crystal report work we need to put  read permission on system drive like C drive in my case. We are not sure where else we need put permission which is getting removed occasionally (every week or so)

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads "invalid file name."  You should consider that your path may be malformed.

What value is in `AppConfig.SitePath`?

Try using `Path.Combine`, like this:

```
var reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppConfig.SitePath, "Form201.rpt");
rptDoc.Load(reportPath);
```

That should ensure that your path is correctly formed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but either way site path is correct otherwise it will always give that error. But as I mentioned it works fine normally without any issue. Once in 10 days suddenly we start getting the error. So report path does not seems an issue.